# Matlab multiple matrix rowwise based on rule

Tags: matlab, row

I have this matrix

```
mp=
2
5
8


fp=
0.67   0.34   0
0.34   0.34   0.34
0      0.5    0.5
```

and this matrix

```
t=
1
1
1
2
3
2
3
```

with this rule:

- if t=1 then the output = mp*(fp first row)
- if t=2 then the output = mp*(fp 2nd row)
- if t=3 then the output = mp*(fp 3rd row)

so the output should be like this:

```
output=
3
3
3
5
6,5
5
6,5
```

im trying using this code
but the output==t

```
[o p]=size(t)
[q r]=size(mp)
for i=1:o;
    j=1:q;

    if t(i)==j
        output=mp*fp(j,:)
    else
        output=t(i)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One line Solution**

you can use the following syntax:

```
output = sum(repmat(mp,1,length(t))'.*fp(t,:),2)
```

**result**

```
ans =
3.0400
3.0400
3.0400
5.1000
6.5000
5.1000
6.5000
```

**example**

```
%variables declaration
fp= [0.67   0.34   0; 0.34   0.34   0.34;0      0.5    0.5];
mp = [2; 5; 8]
t = [1,1,1,2,3,2,3]

%calculates result
output = sum(repmat(mp,1,length(t))'.*fp(t,:),2)
```

Comment: How if there is value that not in t? Fo example t=4 its not in mp or fp?

Answer (score 0):

As your *t* values are already row numbers, you can directly use *t* values for multiplication.

```
mp=[2
5
8] ;

fp=[0.67   0.34   0
0.34   0.34   0.34
0      0.5    0.5] ;
t=[1
1
1
2
3
2
3] ;

iwant = cell(size(t)) ;  % initilaize the required data 

for i = 1:length(t)    % loop for each value of _t_
    iwant{i} = mp*fp(t(i),:) ;
end
```

Comment: i got this output [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]
    [3x3 double]